# What does "over" mean in "three seats over"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I've heard this phrase in a podcast called "Tigerbelly"
One of the podcasters said that "his girlfriend could be sitting 3 seats over and still smell his feet"

I tough it might mean "on the other side of " as in this def

On the other side of: *a village over the border*.
(source freedictionary.com)

I though he meant she was 3 seats away but on the other side of the aisle, as on a plane or bus.

Comment: Did you mean 'smell his feet'?

Comment: "3 seats over" just means "three seats away", doesn't have to be on the other side of an aisle. See [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over) meaning 1- i. In this case the "intervening space" is the space between the two seats (regardless if it actually is a physical space or just a concept of a separation between seats)

Comment: Hmm, weird, I can't find a definition for "over" meaning "away" in any dictionary? Can anyone provide it?

Comment: "across; from one side or place to another" - [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/over) "You can use over to indicate a particular position or place a short distance away from someone or something." - [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/over)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey But I think you'd agree that in the UK "three seats away" would be far more common than "three seats over". I'm wondering if the latter is more American - as someone has quoted Merriam Webster.

Comment: @WS2 - yes, or 'three sets along'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes.

Answer (score 1):

This is OED sense III.6.d for "over, *adv*. and *int*.":

> Further away in the same direction, within a sequence of specified items (as blocks of buildings, etc.).

Here 'over' is an adverb modifying 'sitting.' "She is three seats over" = "she is sitting at a distance of three seats from [whatever the contextual reference point is]."

Comment: Not an expression you hear much in Britain - more likely "three seats away". Did the OED mark it as "US"?

Comment: Yes, this sense is marked "originally US." It does seem more common in the US but I've heard it in the UK as well.